# Cartesian coordinates of the points on the plane in the same order as the Ulam Spiral

Tags: sequences-and-series, visualization

> I'm messing around with doing a visualization that has nothing to do with the primes and in order to execute it correctly I need an ordered list of all point in the order that the Ulam Spiral crosses them. I've tried some of my work but have only run in to abundantly complicated paths to solution. Also is there a name for looking for pattern that generally occur in spiral, whether they are related to primes or not?

E.g.: Starting with this image:

[image]

if $1$ is at the origin, then the list would be as follows: $$(0,0),(1,0),(1,1),(0,1),(-1,1),(-1,0),(-1,-1),(0,-1),(1,-1),‌​(2,-1),(2,0),...$$

Comment: please can you give an example of your phrase? " I need an ordered list of all point in the order that the Ulam Spiral crosses them". In my case, I find it difficult to understand. An example would clarify what you mean.

Comment: Starting with this image https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/1/1d/Ulam_spiral_howto_all_numbers.svg, if 1 is at the origin, then the list would be as follows: (0,0),(1,0),(1,1),(0,1),(-1,1),(-1,0),(-1,-1),(0,-1),(1,-1),(2,-1),(2,0),...

Comment: much better with the example! just in case, I did long time ago a similar question, is not exactly the same, but it might give you ideas. If I can think a solution to your request I will be back! so just in case: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1345430/how-can-i-calculate-the-formula-of-this-fractal-like-structure

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are lucky because it seems that a very similar pair of sequences is already at OEIS.

The $x$-coordinates are sequence [A174344](https://oeis.org/A174344) ("List of $x$-coordinates of point moving in clockwise spiral") and $y$-coordinates ("List of $y$-coordinates of point moving in clockwise spiral") are sequence [A268038](https://oeis.org/A268038).

List of $x$-coordinates of point moving in clockwise spiral.

> $$0, 1, 1, 0, -1, -1, -1, 0, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 0, -1, -2, -2, -2, -2, -2, -1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 2, 1, 0, -1, -2, -3, -3, -3, -3, -3, -3, -3, -2, -1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0, -1, -2, -3, -4, -4, -4, -4, -4, -4, -4, -4, -4, -3, -2, \cdots$$

List of $y$-coordinates of point moving in clockwise spiral.

> $$0, 0, -1, -1, -1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, -1, -2, -2, -2, -2, -2, -1, 0, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 0, -1, -2, -3, -3, -3, -3, -3, -3, -3, -2, -1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 2, 1, 0, -1, -2, -3, -4, -4, -4, -4, -4, -4, -4, -4, -4, -3, -2, -1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 4, \cdots$$

In the referred OEIS pages there are formulas to calculate each sequence of coordinates.

Comment: @AaronQuitta I think this fits your needs... basically OEIS is always a good place to start looking for this kind of sequences. The trick is looking for one of the coordinates only or a description of the sequence. It usually works.

Comment: I guess my only problem now is that the program that I am using for implementation does not work with the type of recursive functions mentioned  in the OEIS pages.

Comment: @AaronQuitta really? they seem very easy to implement... which program are you using? If you are learning for yourself, I would suggest you to learn Python to do your Math tests. Specifically the Anaconda distribution.

Comment: By program I do not mean programming language, what I use is Desoms,  desmos.com/calculator/ .

Answer (score 0):

A piecewise, explicit function is provided by the accepted answer of [a similar question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3157030/parametrizing-the-square-spiral?rq=1).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1888558)