# I need to find an equation to assign a whole, nonnegative ID to every coordinate in an infinite grid.

Tags: functions

I have a math problem I've been trying to solve for a few months. The problem is that I need a function that will take the input of a coordinate pair (from all quadrants [+x +y , +x -y , -x -y , -x +y]) and output a whole nonnegative number with no repeats. I basically need a function that will give me an ID for EVERY coordinate on an INFINITE grid.

The way I started to attack this problem is to form a pattern in which the coordinates would be numbered. I made it so (0,0) is 1, (0,1) is 2, and (-1, 1) is 3 in a spiral pattern around the origin.

After I labeled a coordinate grid with all the 'IDs' or output numbers I started to try to find patterns in the numbers and try to come up with the functions that would give me the correct ID for each of the coordinate pairs. I have found two functions that will each correctly give me a quarter of the infinite coordinate grids IDs .

They are:

If x ≥ |y| 
ID= [(2x+1)^2] -(x-y)

And

If -x ≥ |y|
ID= [(2x)^2] +(x-y)+1

I've been working on this for months and I really need some help. If anyone is willing to take a look and see if you can find anything I will be so greatful.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/398299/looping-in-a-spiral

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2388808

Answer (score 1):

You want a bijection $f:\Bbb Z\times\Bbb Z\to\Bbb N$. Consider the following two bijections
$$g:\Bbb Z\to\Bbb N$$
$$n\mapsto\begin{cases}2n,&\text{if $n$ is positive}\\
1-2n,&\text{otherwise}\end{cases}$$
$$h:\Bbb N\times \Bbb N\to \Bbb N$$
$$ (u,v)\mapsto2^{u-1}(2v-1)$$

Check that $g$ and $h$ are bijections. Now, desired function $f$ is $h\circ (g\times g)$.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a Matlab implementation of the formula(s) one finds in this [OEIS sequence](https://oeis.org/A174344) mentionned in math.stackexchange.com/q/2388808 [I have understood now that your question isn't there] giving a spiral of numbers :

> ```
> % Program A
> a(1)=0;b(1)=0;
> text(a(1),b(1),num2str(1))
> for n=2:99
>    t=mod(floor(sqrt(4*(n-2)+1)),4)*pi/2;
>    a(n) = a(n-1) + sin(t);
>    b(n) = b(n-1) + cos(t);
>    text(a(n),b(n),num2str(n))
> end;
> ```

(this could be converted into complex numbers notations, but I think it wouldn't bring necessarily a big plus).

The "direct access" you desire is given by the following formulas, very close to yours, each one specific to a quadrat :

> ```
>    % Program B
>    clear all;close all;
>    axis(6*[-1,1,-1,1]);axis equal;
>    N=4;% for a (2N+1) x (2N+1) grid
>    % Quadrant I
>    for x=0:N
>        for y=0:N
>            if x<=y
>                r=4*y^2+3*y+1+x;
>            else
>                r=4*x^2-3*x+1-y;
>            end;
>        text(x,y,num2str(r));
>        end;
>    end;
>    % Quadrant II
>    for x=-N:0
>        for y=0:N
>            if abs(x)<=abs(y) 
>                r=4*y^2+3*y+1+x;
>            else
>                r=4*x^2-x+1+y;
>            end;
>        text(x,y,num2str(r));
>        end;
>    end;
>    % Quadrant III
>   for x=-N:0
>        for y=-N:0
>            if abs(x)<abs(y) 
>                r=4*y^2+y+1-x;
>            else
>                r=4*x^2-x+1+y;
>            end;
>        text(x,y,num2str(r));
>        end;
>    end;
>    % Quadrant IV
>    for x=0:N
>        for y=-N:0
>            if abs(x)<abs(y) 
>                r=4*y^2+y+1-x;
>            else
>                r=4*x^2-3*x+1-y;
>            end;
>        text(x,y,num2str(r));
>        end;
>    end;
> ```

Remark : I could have described the operations more formaly, instead of having displayed them into a program, but for the sake of understanding, the result is the same). I am also fairly certain that this program can be shortened ; here again, a more compact form could result in a less understandable  message.

[image]

*Fig. 1. This spiral can be the result as well of Program A or Program B.*

I end this answer by something that is rather independent, but has its own aesthetics. If lines 6 and 7 of Program A are replaced by

> ```
> a(n) = a(n-1) + cos(t) - sin(t);
> b(n) = b(n-1) + cos(t) + sin(t);
> ```

one gets the $45°$ oriented spiral represented in fig. 2. (do you have an idea of the "trick of the trade" behind this slight modification ?)

[image]

*Fig. 2.*

Comment: I have given a second spiral which is maybe the one you were looking for...

Comment: I'm sorry for not explaining things very well, I'm in 9th grade. I'm not looking for a function to make the spiral, I'm looking for a function that will take x and y and out put the corresponding number on the spiral. (0,0) is 1. if I input 0 0 into the function [(2x+1)^2] -(x-y) the output will be 1, which is what I want.

Comment: I understand. As a consequence, I have completely revamped my answer. Is it satisfactory now ?

Comment: The fact that it is second degree polynomials that bring a response doesn't come by surprise (when you think to [Ulam's spiral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ulam_spiral) and phenomena like the sequence of primes having the form $n^2+n+41$

Comment: You haven't answered me though my program B gives (now) the formulas for each quadrant.  If I input (x,y) after checking in which quadrant it is, I can compute the value to be placed there...

Comment: What I meant is an equation that I could do by hand. Not a program. I solved it anyway but thank you for trying to help.